# Docker Base Image - which flavour?

Tags: docker

We're running a Java based Webshop on SLES12.

Currently we're deciding if we want to run the Webshop in Future as a Docker Container.

At least in our Test-Environment we will host the Webshop as Docker Container.

My Question is now: How important is it to choose the base image of the Docker Container as Production near as possible? Which means: is it necessary (or recommendable) to build the Docker Container on a SLES (or opensuse) Base Image or is it OK to keep Debian as Base Image?

What's the major difference between Debian and Suse base Images (except Packaging Tool, directoy structure and Base Image Size)

Answer (score 0):

> How important is it to choose the base image of the Docker Container as Production near as possible?

It is not important. It is **mandatory**. You docker image have to be as near as possible from your prod environment if you intend to use docker to develop and not in prod.

> Which means: is it necessary (or recommendable) to build the Docker Container on a SLES (or opensuse) Base Image or is it OK to keep Debian as Base Image?

If you are not running your project via docker in prod, you need to be the nearest so if you are running on debian, use debian as base image. If you intend to run on prod with docker, it is better to keep the image as light   as possible (the more if you intend to make it public). But keeping debian base is ok.